# Is it possible to access keyword arguments passed to a Field in a Pydantic BaseModel?

Tags: python, pydantic

I need to access  `my_key` in a Pydantic `Field`, as shown below:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: str = Field(default=None, my_key=7)

    def print_field_objects(self):
        for obj in self.something_something:  # What do I use here
            print(obj.my_key)                 # ... so that i can use my_key?
```

I tried to see what `self` contains, like `self.__dict__` but I wasn't able to find it. Is it even possible to access `my_key`?

I need it for my FastAPI endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the [model's JSON Schema representation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/) using the `BaseModel`'s `.schema()` method, and then rely on this functionality of [`Field` customization](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customization) that:

> `**` any other keyword arguments (e.g. `examples`) will be added verbatim to the field's schema

In other words, any other arbitrary keyword arguments passed to `Field` that isn't consumed or used by Pydantic (or by any custom creation/instantiation) would be present in that field's JSON Schema representation.

So, in this case, your `my_key` should be present on the *model*'s schema:

```
In [4]: class MyModel(BaseModel):
   ...:     x: str = Field(default=None, my_key=7)
   ...: 

In [5]: MyModel.schema()
Out[5]: 
{'title': 'MyModel',
 'type': 'object',
 'properties': {'x': {'title': 'X', 'my_key': 7, 'type': 'string'}}}
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    ||||||||||||
```

You can then have an instance method that looks like this:

```
In [21]: class MyModel(BaseModel):
    ...:     x: str = Field(default=None, my_key=7)
    ...:     y: int = Field(default=1, my_key=42)
    ...: 
    ...:     def print_field_objects(self):
    ...:         for field_name, field in self.schema()["properties"].items():
    ...:             print(field["my_key"])
    ...: 

In [22]: m1 = MyModel()

In [23]: m1.print_field_objects()
7
42
```

But, since a model's schema and `Field` definitions are tied to the *class*, not the *instance*, multiple instances would have the same value:

```
In [28]: m1 = MyModel()

In [29]: m1.print_field_objects()
7
42

In [30]: m2 = MyModel()

In [31]: m2.print_field_objects()
7
42
```

So, it would be more accurate to make it a class method instead, since `my_key` won't change anyway with different values of the field `x` or with different instances:

```
In [35]: class MyModel(BaseModel):
    ...:     x: str = Field(default=None, my_key=7)
    ...:     y: int = Field(default=1, my_key=42)
    ...: 
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def print_field_objects(cls):
    ...:         for field_name, field in cls.schema()["properties"].items():
    ...:             print(field_name, field.get("my_key"))
    ...: 

In [36]: MyModel.print_field_objects()
x 7
y 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Field [doesn't take arbitrary arguments](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customization), what exactly are you trying to achieve, perhaps there's a more appropriate solution.

Per your other question, x is a class attribute, whose definition can be found in `self.__class__.__fields__`, while its *instance* value can be found by calling `self.x`

Comment: I need to store more info in the field definition. I am making filters somewhat similar to django-rest-framework. I store them in there just to define my filters in a bit more clear way.

Comment: Using your answer I managed to access the value: `self.__class__.__fields__['x'].field_info.extra['my_key']`, thanks! Is this a rightway to do it?

Comment: There is! `CompanyFilter.schema()['MyModel']['x']['my_key']`. Thank you, you guided me in the right direction. Could you adapt your answer and I ll gladly accept it.